# Calling 2 Different Databases

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to have the PAYPAL IPN work with 2 different sites, I can't get the php script to know which database to work with. Here's my script.

```
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// If testing on Sandbox use:
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


// assign posted variables to local variables
$custom = $_POST['item_name'];

//Config file for 1st database
if($custom=="1"){
require_once("../config.php");

//Script to execute

}

 //Config file for 2nd database (different site)
if($custom=="2"){
require_once("../config.php");

//Script to execute
}
```

Comment: You have not provided sufficient information, for example, on which value you want to decide which db to use. Also, some issues confusing to me --- you are taking `item_name` in a variable named `$custom`. It is confusing because, there is an optional post field named `custom`. Again, you are comparing `item_name` to some numbers! Were you looking for `item_number` in the first place? Though there is no restriction to put an integer in `item_name`,but it is more natural to put the number in `item_number` and put the descriptive name is `item_name`. I would suggest you to double check the cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is making a lot of assumptions and isn't very defensive. It's assuming the form was *posted*, that it was successfully populated, that `$_POST['item_name']` will contain only the strings '1' or '2' and that your script is running in a path which is one folder deep to a directory containing config.php...and that regardless of the condition, the same config.php will be loaded and miraculously know what it needs to do.

What would make more sense is something like this:

```
try
{
    if(isset($_POST['site_name']))
    {
        require_once('../configs/' . $_POST['site_name'] . '/config.php');
        if(!isset($some_var_declared_inside_config_file))
        {
            throw new Exception('Config not loaded');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Site name not provided');
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Then you could have your configs setup like so:

```
/www/paypal.php
/configs/sitea/config.php
/configs/siteb/config.php
/configs/sitec/config.php
```

Comment: The variable to let me know which site it is, is a custom field that paypal IPN sends back to me so I can collect the payment details. Right now it's set as 1, 2 , or 3 depending on the site. I'll try out your suggestion, may take a sec for me to find out if this will work.

Comment: If Paypal is sending the site name back to you (can we assume it's from a cURL response?), it wouldn't be inside `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

I found a great script for this that worked great. It automatically send the paypal response to the correct site based on the email.

http://www.scriptomart.com/view-item/15-Paypal-IPN-Multiple-Email-Accounts.html is the script but the one I bought wasn't free so you may have to look for that one. I can't find the exact link.